# Is it possible to deserialize only a portion of a serialized file

Tags: c#, serialization

First of all, I am a beginner in this area of serialization in C#. So please bear with me if some things I mention sound weird.
I have a serialized file which consists of several List arrays. For example:-

```
List of Teachers;  
List of Students;
```

Both Teachers and Students were derived from the `ISerializable` Interface and hold serializable attributes in it.

Now I have the serialized file, lets call it `classes.data` file.
Is there anyway I can deserialize only one portion of this serialized file?
For example I just want to read the List of Teachers. Do I have to read the complete serialized file `classes.data` and then retrieve the list of teachers?
Or is there anyway I can just deserialize the list of teachers as a List object hence making the deserializing faster?

Please help as this is one of my projects.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Update : I am working on c#

Samuel

Comment: Why do you need deserialize only some portion of it? In general - the only way is to deserialize whole file. You can try magic like interpreting binary format of file - but I am sure you do NOT need this.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer; No. It may although depend on which language you are using, but if my guess (Java) is correct th answer is no. It sounds like you'd rather turn to for example JSON to store your data, or a database, or both.

Serialization is not meant to be used as a way to store large amounts of data (like lists), you should use a database or if it's simply a list or two; JSON.

Info about JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Library for working with JSON in Java: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/